# Javafx How to set coordinates of a popup?

Tags: popup, javafx-2

When a popup is launched on tab of a text filed, How to set x,y coordinates of popup such that it gets displayed below the text filed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used popup menu. and here is code for showing popup at correct location. You 
can try this...

```
ContextMenu popup=new ContextMenu();
MenuItem itemAdd=new MenuItem("Add/Edit");
MenuItem itemDel=new MenuItem("Delete");
popup.getItems().add(itemAdd);        
popup.getItems().add(itemDel);    


txtBox.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent t) 
{
    txt=(TextBox)t.getSource();
    if(t.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY )
    {
        popup.show(txt,t.getScreenX(),t.getScreenY());                   
    }
}
```

Comment: getScreenX(), getScreenY() methods are available in only MouseEvent class. How to get coordinates from keyEvent or ActionEvent?

Comment: You will not get getScreenX(), getScreenY() coordinates from keyEvent or ActionEvent so You have to calculate coordinates manually.

Comment: Suppose you are trying to show pop up at any TextBox then you have to calculate coordinates of that textbox.

Comment: i am able to show popup below the upper left corner of textbox.But how to show it below lower left corner?
I am using this code `Point2D txtCoords =txtBox.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);popup.show(txtBox,txtCoords .getX() + txtBox.getScene().getX() + txtBox.getScene().getWindow().getX(),txtCoords .getY() + txtBox.getScene().getY() + txtBox.getScene().getWindow().getY());` to show popup.

Comment: Try this...Calculate all values of textBox's parent like its stage,substage or if it is on any AnchorPane(ap) then....+event.getSceneX() for X and +event.getSceneY()+textBox.getHieght() for Y.

`Mainstage.getX()+subAP.getLayoutX()+event.getSceneX(),
Mainstage.getY()+subAP.getLayoutY()+event.getSceneY()+txtBox.getHeight()`